# Get data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use Adapter for Push Notification. I followed all steps define in this IBM Worklight Developer site for Push Notification and make a project and its working. Now further i want to send notifications to a specific device. For this worklight give a method getDeviceSubscriptions() which return JSON array containing number of object for each subscribed device.

```
deviceSubscriptions = userSubscription.getDeviceSubscriptions() ;
```

the JSON include:

```
[{
    "platform": "",
    "eventSourceId": "",
    "alias": "",
    "token": "",
    "userAgent": "",
    "device": "",
    "applicationId": "",
    "options": {}
},
```

{

```
   "platform": "",
    "eventSourceId": "",
    "alias": "",
    "token": "",
    "userAgent": "",
    "device": "",
    "applicationId": "",
    "options": {}
}]
```

Now i want to get value of key `device` and token. So how can it can be achieved.

At that time i am using `JSON.stringify` it return a string but i want to have direct access to device and token. When i used `JSON.parse` it gives `[object , Object]` but not display any JSON.

Comment: That json code isn't valid, is it intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the JSON parse, use this to point out the key directly

```
obj[0]["device"]
```

For all the available node you should use incremental value in place of [0], like

```
obj[i]["device"];
i++;
```

Comment: its not working gives error: "Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot find default value for object.

Comment: I have just pasted your json string in http://jsonlint.com/, it's gives me error.

Comment: [{
    "platform": "",
    "eventSourceId": "",
    "alias": "",
    "token": "",
    "userAgent": "",
    "device": "",
    "applicationId": "",
    "options": {}
}]

Comment: Yes, it's valid now, so parse the json in an object and grab it like, object[0]["token"], you can see the object index if you paste this json in, http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27458/discussion-between-user95280-and-sudip-pal)

Answer (score 0):

Just access the properties using array syntax:

```
var firstDevice=deviceSubscriptions[0].device;
var secondDevice=deviceSubscriptions[1].device;
```

etc...

Comment: its not working gives error: "Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot find default value for object.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Currently your JSON is not valid, the valid json should be :

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "platform": "Google",
            "eventSourceId": "PushAdapter.PushEventSource",
            "alias": "myPush",
            "token": " ",
            "userAgent": " ",
            "device": " ",
            "applicationId": " ",
            "options": {}
        },
        {
            "platform": "Google",
            "eventSourceId": "PushAdapter.PushEventSource",
            "alias": "myPush",
            "token": " ",
            "userAgent": " ",
            "device": " ",
            "applicationId": " ",
            "options": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Parse your json string like :

```
var data = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
```

Now access the device and token properties value like:

```
var device = data.items[0].device;        //give device value of 0th item
   
var token = data.items[0].token;          //give token value of 0th item
```

[**Check this fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/umezas/4/edit)

Comment: its not working gives error: "Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot find default value for object.